# Not able to connect to Sharepoint 2013 using command line

Tags: document-library, network-drive

I was using net use command to connect to the Sharepoint 2010 and it is working fine. When I try to connect to Sharepoint 2013 with same command, it gives the error "System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found."

I was trying to connect to Document Library is something like
https://mysharepoint.net/dir/perdir/TestDocumentLibrary/

Can you please suggest me the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solve it step by step

- First open the Library in Explorer through the UI
- Then try to make the NET USE mapping

Most common cause is your Browser does not have access... and your WebDAV connection is controlled through the Browser

http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/10/06/how-to-access-a-office-365-document-library-from-windows-explorer.aspx